# Keras: How to get layer index when already know layer name?

Tags: python, keras

I already knew the name of a layer of a model, now I want to know that layer's index.
Is there any available function to do that?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose your model is `model` and the `layerName` is name of the layer.

```
index = None
for idx, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
    if layer.name == layerName:
        index = idx
        break
```

Here `index` is the idx of required name.

Answer (score 5):

The answer of Akhilesh as function:

```
def getLayerIndexByName(model, layername):
    for idx, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
        if layer.name == layername:
            return idx
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way of doing that is as follows:

```
layer_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]
layer_idx = layer_names.index(your_layer_name)
```

If you are doing visualization in keras, you can also achieve that as follows:

```
from vis.utils import utils
layer_idx = utils.find_layer_idx(model, your_layer_name)
```